# Generic Wrapper around Generic Repositories using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, reflection, n-tier-architecture

I'm trying to practise loose coupling and seperating everything in an n-tier architecture, but I'm stuck on - what I believe - basic stuff. My number one issue is references. I'm constantly moving classes between assemblies because Class A needs Class B, but can't reach it, so lets move Class B -- and then I break Class C.

This is the best I could come up with.

### Step 1: Architecture

**Project.Data**

- Entities (POCO)

**Project.DataAccess**

- Context
- Migrations
- Repositories
- Unit of work
- ViewModels

**Project.Web**

- Controllers
- Views

---

### Step 2: Use Project.DataAccess as glue between Presentation and Data

I am using the Unit of Work pattern, but that requires access to the POCOs, so I can't use the UoW in my Controller. Therefore I thought it would be a good plan to create wrapper/service called `ViewModelService`. This service instantiates the UoW and returns AutoMapped Viewmodels to my controller.

However ...

My UoW/Repository patterns is generic, so I'm trying to make my service generic too.

## IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TObject>
{
    IQueryable<TObject> All();
    IQueryable<TObject> Filter(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate);

    IQueryable<TObject> Filter<TKey>(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> filter,
        out int total, int index = 0, int size = 50);

    bool Contains(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate);
    TObject Find(params object[] keys);
    TObject Find(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate);
    TObject Create(TObject t);
    int Delete(TObject t);
    int Delete(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate);
    int Update(TObject t);
    void Ignore(TObject t);

    int Count { get; }
}
```

## Generic BaseRepository

```
public class BaseRepository<TObject> : IRepository<TObject>
    where TObject : class
{
    protected AppDbContext Context = null;

    public BaseRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    protected DbSet<TObject> DbSet
    {
        get { return Context.Set<TObject>(); }
    }

    public virtual int Count
    {
        get { return Queryable.Count<TObject>(DbSet); }
    }

   // ... (You get the picture)
}
```

## UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context = new AppDbContext();

    private BaseRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
    private BaseRepository<Product> _productRepository;
    private BaseRepository<ApplicationUser> _userRepository;
    private bool _disposed;

    public BaseRepository<Order> OrderRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_orderRepository == null)
            {
                _orderRepository = new BaseRepository<Order>(_context);
            }
            return _orderRepository;
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository<Product> ProductRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_productRepository == null)
            {
                _productRepository = new BaseRepository<Product>(_context);
            }
            return _productRepository;
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository<ApplicationUser> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userRepository == null)
            {
                _userRepository = new BaseRepository<ApplicationUser>(_context);
            }
            return _userRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

So right now - without the "service" and the new n-tier layers - I use this in my Controllers.

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    // GET: /Product/
    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.All();
        return View(model);
    }

// Etc...
```

But now that I am dividing everything up into seperate layers, I can't do that. And I don't want to have my Unit of Work class to map the ViewModels.

Here is my attempt to create this "service" (not sure it's even the correct name for it):

## ViewModelService

```
 public class ViewModelService : IViewModelService
 {
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    public T GetSingle<T>(int key)
    {
        // Get appropriate repository based on T1?

        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now I am faced with the issue -- how do I make sure that when I call:

`_viewModelService.GetSingle<ProductVM>(id);`

it figures out - by itself (via reflection?) - that it should call:

`_unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Find(id)`

internally inside the repository?

*Wow, I feel I did a terrible job explaining that! :)*

### TL;DR

I have a **UnitOfWork** class:

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbContext _context = new DbContext();

    private BaseRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
    private BaseRepository<Product> _productRepository;
    private BaseRepository<ApplicationUser> _userRepository;
    private bool _disposed;

    public BaseRepository<Order> OrderRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_orderRepository == null)
            {
                _orderRepository = new BaseRepository<Order>(_context);
            }
            return _orderRepository;
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository<Product> ProductRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_productRepository == null)
            {
                _productRepository = new BaseRepository<Product>(_context);
            }
            return _productRepository;
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository<ApplicationUser> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userRepository == null)
            {
                _userRepository = new BaseRepository<ApplicationUser>(_context);
            }
            return _userRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a **generic wrapper**:

```
public class ViewModelService : IViewModelService
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    public T GetSingle<T>(int key)
    {
        // Get appropriate repository based on T1?

        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I use **reflection** so that when I ask for `GetSingle<ProductVM>(id)` the wrapper will translate that into a call to `_unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Find(id);` -- so the wrapper knows to call the correct repository inside the UoW.

Whew.

Comment: maybe you can just create something like `unitOfWork.GetRepository<ProductVM>()`, that will create needed typed repository. And then in that GetSingle method you will use instance of repository, and save id to local dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approaches is to have a generic abstract class and let the concrete child class override this specific piece that provides actual repository. This way most of the code can be put in the abstract class and still precisely provide what is needed at the child class level.

```
 // two generic types
 // TDTO - view model type
 // TDomain - domain type
 public abstract class AbstractViewModelService<TDTO, TDomain> : IViewModelService
 {
     private UnitOfWork _uow { get; }        

     public AbstractViewModelService( UnitOfWork uow )
     {
         this._uow = uow;
     }

     public abstract IRepository<TDomain> Repository { get; }

     public TDTO GetSingle<TDTO>(int key)
     {
         // Get appropriate repository based on T1?
         // it is here ->

         return Mapper.DynamicMap<TDTO>( this.Repository.Find( key ) );
     }
 }

 public class UserViewModelService : AbstractViewModelService<UserDto, User> 
 {
     public override IRepository<User> Repository
     {
         get
         {
             return this._uow.UserRepository;
         }
     }
     ...
 }

 public class AccountViewModelService : AbstractViewModelService<AccountDto, Account> 
 {
     public override IRepository<Account> Repository
     {
         get
         {
             return this._uow.AccountRepository;
         }
     }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Would this not create tight coupling between my controller and the UserViewModelService and other services?

Comment: And is there any other approach? You could possibly abstract all these services and make them injectable but I see no point in that. This is why you have your repository - to abstract the database layer. Abstracting higher layers sounds like an overkill.

Comment: I agree to the overkill. I am abstracting the repository because it returns entities from the Data layer, which my controller does not have access to. So I try to create a middleman that returns a viewmodel instead. Where do I alter my design? Do I need to expose my entities to my presentation layer?

Comment: Your design is ok, abstracting the repository is ok and having a concrete layer of services is ok. Domain entities don't have to be exposed, this was yours direction to create a service layer that maps domain to dtos and this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use MEF?
break your UOW that it will compose the repositories - also you will benefit that you will don't have the duplication of

```
get
    {
        if (_productRepository == null)
        {
            _productRepository = new BaseRepository<Product>(_context);
        }
        return _productRepository;
    }
```

add metadata to each export item and then in

```
 public T GetSingle<T>(int key)
{
    // Get appropriate repository based on T1?

    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

you can get the correct plugin according to the metadata that it expose.
or you can add all your repositories to ServiceLoactor, so you can write
instead of

```
_unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Find(id);

ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>().find(id)
```